# DoH proxy on nginx not working

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to proxy/redirect DoH query's on my Nginx server to a different DoH URL. This my Nginx configs. I'm also open to other tutorials (links and video)

```
        ...
location /private/doh/xxxx/dns-query {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Connection "";
            proxy_pass https://dns.google/dns-query/;
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide the corresponding error & access logs.
Additionally what would be the expected behaviour: what is the exact request you are sending and the answer you are expecting, could be helpful.

Comment: thanks for your respond. in Nginx no error is logged. In opera its: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED and in Android in Intra its: HTTP_ERROR and in browser its: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG.